# Are static variables initialised from a file initialised only once

Tags: java, static

I am creating a class in Java to represent a String and a Color, called ColoredString.  I wanted to be able to create one of these objects using a color name of any color recognized by the .Net framework. Such a list of colors is here: http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/colours.php. Since Java doesn't have as comprehensive a list of "known colors", my solution was to have my program read from a file to populate a list of known colors to use. So, I made a text file following this format:

```
AliceBlue #F0F8FF
AntiqueWhite #FAEBD7
Aqua #00FFFF
Aquamarine #7FFFD4
```

The first word is a color name and the second is in the format #RRGGBB to specify the color code. Since I obviously wouldn't want to read from the file every time I call the constructor for a ColoredString, I thought I might have it read into a static variable, in hopes that when my program runs, this file would be read once and create a single instance of this static variable to be referenced by any instance of a ColoredString. Here is the code I wrote to do this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ColoredString {

    public static final ArrayList<KnownColor> knownColors = setKCs();

    private static ArrayList<KnownColor> setKCs() {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("dotNet_knownColors.txt"));) {
            ArrayList<KnownColor> knownColors = new ArrayList<>();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String colorName = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
                String colorCode = scanner.next().toUpperCase();
                knownColors.add(new KnownColor(colorName, colorCode));
            }
            return knownColors;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
            System.out.println("uh-oh...");
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static final String defaultColor = "black";
    private Color color;
    private String string;

    public ColoredString(String color, String string) {
        if (color == null || color.equals("")) {
            color = defaultColor;
        }
        color = color.toLowerCase();
        this.string = string;
        if (color.startsWith("#")) {
            this.color = new Color(Integer.parseInt(color.substring(1), 16));
        } else {
            this.color = getColorByName(color);
        }
    }

    public ColoredString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
        this.color = getColorByName(defaultColor);//default color

    }

    private static Color getColorByName(String name) {
        for (KnownColor c : knownColors) {
            if (c.name.equals(name)) {
                String colorCode = c.rgbHexNum;
                return new Color(Integer.parseInt(colorCode.substring(1), 16));
            }
        }
        return getColorByName(defaultColor);
    }

    private static class KnownColor {

        public final String name;
        public final String rgbHexNum;

        public KnownColor(String name, String rgbHexNum) {
            this.name = name;
            this.rgbHexNum = rgbHexNum;
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is this: will my code do as I said and only read from the file once, and only create a single instance of the variable knownColors, even if I create many instances of my class?

Comment: Did you test it? Add some `println()`s and it'll tell you. Also, you might be interested in `static {...}` (static initialization blocks).

Comment: static variables are initialized in the first place, before invoking any 'new' operator, one static variable has one instance, so answer to your last question is yes.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, thanks. That is a much simpler way to initialize my variable. I didn't know about static initialization blocks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Java first. Below is java 8; and I used `javafx.scene.paint.Color` as Oracle sees JavaFX as successor to AWT/Swing.

It can do 148 color names.

First a test on your colors:

```
    String[] colorNames = { "aquamarine", "Aquamarine", "AntiqueWhite" };
    // List with color as hex, with alpha component as FF
    for (String colorName : colorNames) {
        Color color = Color.valueOf(colorName);
        System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", colorName, color);
    }
```

Then all color constants:

```
    for (Field field : Color.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
        if (Modifier.isPublic(modifiers) && Modifier.isStatic(modifiers)
                && Modifier.isFinal(modifiers) && field.getType() == Color.class) {
            String colorName = field.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            Color color = Color.valueOf(colorName);
            System.out.printf("- %s -> %s%n", colorName, color);
        }
    }
```

This uses reflection, and assumes that the constant name is a human readable name.

```
[139] thistle -> 0xd8bfd8ff
[140] tomato -> 0xff6347ff
[141] turquoise -> 0x40e0d0ff
[142] violet -> 0xee82eeff
[143] wheat -> 0xf5deb3ff
[144] white -> 0xffffffff
[145] whitesmoke -> 0xf5f5f5ff
[146] yellow -> 0xffff00ff
[147] yellowgreen -> 0x9acd32ff
```

Answer (score 1):

From a brief look... Yes.

If you want to be sure, why not debug your program with a breakpoint in the code that loads from the file and see how often it gets hit? Or temporarily add some code to System.out.println something in that code.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Only one instance of knownColors will be created :)